# when i apply share intent myapplication get closed in android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

My problem is when  I use share event at that time, my first activity get closed

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            MenuItem shareItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

            ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider();

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");`enter code here`
            String Scategory_id = global.getcategoryid();
        }
       <item
            android:id="@+id/action_share"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

ABOVE CODE APPLY IN MENU. XML AND I GET THE PROBLEM WHEN I USE SHARE INTENT MY MAIN APPLICATION GET CLOSED ACTCHULY ITS AFTER USING SHARE BUTTON ITS SHOULD BE REDIRECT ON MY FIRST APPLICATION

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setShareIntent on mShare.

```
mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```